# Want to kill my tab but process.kill() doesn't work

Tags: python, kill-process, taskkill

no error but still cannot kill the process

```
import time
import subprocess
total_breaks = 3
break_count = 0
print("This program started on " + time.ctime())
while(break_count < total_breaks):
    time.sleep(5)
    process = subprocess.Popen([r'F:\software\firefox\Firefox.exe',
'-new-tab', 'http://www.google.com/'])
    time.sleep(6)
    process.kill()
    break_count = break_count + 1
```

I expected to kill my tab because it ain't showing error but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked automatically after reopening...I don't know why?